# javascript change background color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Can you show me Javascript that allows you to change the background color of the page to another color. For example, I have a blue background color and I want to change it to green. The color must be changed when the user presses a button that triggers the event.
I saw that it exists on many sites but I could not write the code
I write in REACTJS I would love to have your help

Thanks...

Comment: Are you using a js framework?

Comment: As a new user it is important to understand that SO is not a tutorial site. Please  review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 10):

If you want change background color on button click, you should use JavaScript function and change a style in the HTML page.

```
function chBackcolor(color) {
   document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

It is a function in JavaScript for change color, and you will be call this function in your event, for example :

```
<input type="button" onclick="chBackcolor('red');">
```

I recommend to use **jQuery** for this.

If you want it only for some seconds, you can use `setTimeout` function:

```
window.setTimeout("chBackColor()",10000);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the background color of an object using CSS.

You can also use JavaScript to attach click handlers to objects and they can change the style of an object using `element.style.property = 'value';`. In the example below I've attached it in the HTML to a button but the handler could equally have been added to the body element or defined entirely in JavaScript.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';">Green</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggest that you learn about Jquery, most popular JS library. 
With jquery it's simple to acomplish what you want.Simle example below:

```
$(“#DIV_YOU_WANT_CHANGE”).click(function() {
    $(this).addClass(“.your_class_with_new_color”);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find solutions for both your problems.

```
document.body.style.height = '500px';
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var self = this,
        old_bg = this.style.background;

    this.style.background = this.style.background=='green'? 'blue':'green';
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.style.background = old_bg;
    }, 1000);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ea1xf3sx/

Answer (score 0):

You can sets the body's background colour using `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";` so this can be put into a function that's called when the user clicks.
The next part can be done by using `document.getElementByID("divID").style.backgroundColor = "red";` `window.setTimeout("yourFunction()",10000);` which calls yourFunction in 10 seconds to change the colour back.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this---

```
<input type="button" onClick="changebackColor">
//changes background color to black on click
function changebackColor(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
document.getElementById("divID").style.backgroundColor = "black";      
window.setTimeout("yourFunction()",10000);
}
```

Comment: getElementByID -> getElementById

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()`:

```js
var addBg = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  el.className = 'bg';
  setTimeout(function() {
    removeBg(el);
  }, 10 * 1000); //<-- (in miliseconds)
};

var removeBg = function(el) {
  el.className = '';
};
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.bg {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<body onclick='addBg(event);'>This is body
  <br/>
  <div onclick='addBg(event);'>This is div
  </div>
</body>
```

Using jQuery:

```js
var addBg = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var el = $(this);
  el.addClass('bg');
  setTimeout(function() {
    removeBg(el);
  }, 10 * 1000); //<-- (in miliseconds)
};

var removeBg = function(el) {
  $(el).removeClass('bg');
};

$(function() {
  $('body, div').on('click', addBg);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.bg {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>This is body
  <br/>
  <div>This is div</div>
</body>
```