# change background of underlying div on a hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this: on hover of my a element in my nav change the background color of a .background, my code is like so:

```
        <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="background"></div>
</nav>
```

However the color only changes when I tell the css to change the color on hover of the `ul` and if I tell to change it when I hover over an `a` with class `.header-about` it just won't do anything no matter what I try. I tried to be as clear as possible in explaining this.

Here is my whole mark-up:

```css
.header-nav .background {
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 550px;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.header-nav ul .header-about:hover {
  color: black;
}

.header-nav ul .header-about:hover + .background {
  background: #2F94CC;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-nav text-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#about" class="header-about">About</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#work">My work</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#resume">Resumé</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="background"></div>
</nav>
```

I tried to be as clear as possible in explaining the problem.

Comment: Hi can you put this in a fiddle?

Comment: `+` works only for next adjacent sibling element. In your case, you are actually looking for sibling element of the parent element. which is not possible using css.

Comment: you can find a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089414/javascript-change-background-color-on-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select `.background` with CSS on hover of `.header-about`. However you can achieve this as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.header-nav ul a').hover(function() {
    $('.background').css('background', $(this).attr('data-color'));
  }, function() {
    $('.background').css('background', '');
  });
});
```

```css
.header-nav .background {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 550px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
}

.header-nav ul li:hover {
  color: black;
}

.header-nav .background {
  background: #2F94CC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="header-nav text-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#about" data-color="#f00">About</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#work" data-color="#0f0">My work</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#resume" data-color="#05f">Resumé</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#contact" data-color="#f00">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="background"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: i see what you are doing, but it's not quite what i am looking for, i want to know if it is possible to choose a background color on hover for every link. say about makes it blue, work makes it red etc. is it still a good practical to use css instead of javascript? because i don't have much knowledge about it so i like to avoid it until i know javascript better.

Comment: @erpseboy yes, its good to use pure css unless it becomes necessary then we should look for JavaScript solutions. I've updated my answer may be it will help you

Comment: thanks!! I really appreciate your help. this is coming close, I am starting to think JavaScript is the way to go here, because of the flashes of purple in between hover actions over multiple links it is not transitioning as smoothly as i had hoped to achieve. do you have any suggestions? because I am a complete newbie to JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Your next sibling selector which is '+' will only work if the background div is positioned like this:

```
<nav class="header-nav text-left">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a data-scroll href="#about" class="header-about">About</a>
          <div class="background"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a data-scroll href="#work">My work</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll href="#resume">Resumé</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Because it has to be after your selector element at the same level in the dom tree and next to your selected element.

You might have to go for a javascript solution if the positioning in your html cannot be changed.