# How do I change background when click on it?

Tags: javascript

```
 <li data-pos="A">Text1</li>
 <li data-pos="B">Text2</li>
```

Now I want to create a JavaScript function that will change background, when click on it.

```
data-pos="A" backgrund change to blue.
data-pos="B" backgrund change to Red.
```

How can I do that? with JavaScript

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-background-color-after-clicking-the-button-in-javascript/#:~:text=Use%20HTML%20DOM%20Style%20backgroundColor,with%20the%20help%20of%20JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript change background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089414/javascript-change-background-color-on-click)

Comment: Are you related to this guy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981212/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-list-style-when-click

Comment: Change background of the LI or of the page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set an event-listener and set the `color` on `click` according to the `dataset.pos` of the click `li` element:

```js
const POS_COLOR_MAP = { A: 'blue', B: 'red' };

function setColor(listItem) {
  const color = POS_COLOR_MAP[listItem.dataset['pos']];
  if(color) listItem.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
document.getElementById("myList").addEventListener("click", event => {
  if(event.target && event.target.nodeName == "LI") setColor(event.target);
});
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li data-pos="A">Text1</li>
  <li data-pos="B">Text2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate and use a class

I assume you want to change the background color of the LI here

```js
document.getElementById('myList').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.dataset.pos) tgt.classList.toggle('selected');
})
```

```css
[data-pos=A].selected {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

[data-pos=B].selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li data-pos="A">Text1</li>
  <li data-pos="B">Text2</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to change page background you could use the data attribute for that too

```js
document.getElementById('myList').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.dataset.pos) document.body.style.backgroundColor={"A":"blue","B":"red"}[tgt.dataset.pos];
})
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li data-pos="A">Text1</li>
  <li data-pos="B">Text2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access li whose having your data attibute then change color depending on data attibute value

See below working snippet :

```js
var liElement = document.querySelectorAll("li[data-pos]");


liElement.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = e.target.dataset['pos']

  })

})
```

```css
li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<li data-pos="blue">Blue</li>
<li data-pos="red">Red</li>
```

Comment: @mplungjan , yep it could be , that will prevent extra loop  event binding

Answer (score -1):

```
 <button onClick="foo()"> </button>


<script> 
      
      function foo(){
        //select your element whose background color changed
         document.getElementById("selector").style.backgroundColor = "red";
       }
</script>
```

You can use something like this shown above.

Comment: He wants to click on the LI and change the background color of the clicked LI

Comment: No matters what he wants to select i show him some codes how its work. He can search JS DOM.