# How to change background of div using button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "name", "password", "database");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name, city, subject FROM user");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $output = '<div class="block" style="background: grey">
          <form method="post">
          <p>Name: '.$result['name'].'</p>
          <p>Subject: '.$result['subject'].'</p>
          <p>City: '.$result['city'].'</p>
          <input type="button" name="grey" value="grey">
          <input type="button" name="red" value="red">
          </form>
          </div>';

    echo $output;
}
?>
```

How can I change background color of `<div class="block">` using buttons `<input type="button" name="grey" value="grey">` and `<input type="button" name="red" value="red">`? I tried to do it, but nothing helps. Who knows?
P.S.: it doesn't matter, what to use (PHP or JS).

Comment: please show how you've tried.

Comment: I don't know JS at all, but I found some ways like this: 

`var input = document.getElementById("my_input_id");

input.onclick = function ()
{
    document.getElementById("my_div").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};`

Comment: Sorry, if my question is weird, but I really don't know how to do it, because I don't use JS at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript change background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089414/javascript-change-background-color-on-click)

Comment: To some extent it helped, but I have a lot of divs, so I don't know how to do that, because I have never used JS

Comment: If you never used JS, then go learn some JS first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for do that you can use javascript. I suggest to change the class of the div when button is clicked and add the good rules in css, or just change style property of the element. But css is here for taht and it's more clean to do that with classes and css. You have also to add an id to the button like #red or #blue
Exemple with classes :

```
const div = document.querySelector('.block');
const btnRed = document.querySelector('#red');
const btnBlue = document.querySelector('#blue');
    
// Get the click on the button
btnRed.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Change classes
    div.classList.add('red');
    div.classList.remove('blue');
    // If you don't want to use classes, change the background property
    div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
})
```

And it's the contrary for the blue button

If you have several div,I think you can do that :

```
const div = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
const btnRed = document.querySelector('#red');
const btnBlue = document.querySelector('#blue');
    
// Get the click on the button
btnRed.addEventListener('click', () => {
div.forEach(item => {
    // Change classes
    item.classList.add('red');
    item.classList.remove('blue');
    // If you don't want to use classes, change the background property
    item.style.backgroundColor = "red";
})
})
```

Comment: It works for only one block, but there a lot of them. What can I do to make them all change color? But of course, thank you so much!

Comment: You can use document.querySelectorAll at const div, do a foreach and change class or background color The code is in my previous answer